# Xml file (on a server) Based Authentication for a desktop application possible?

Tags: c#, xml, authentication

I am developing a Desktop  application  using c#. This application would require  users to login  before using it .

I plan to have an xml file on a server (which is  not public to view) .

When the user logs in to the application using a username and password it would check with the xml file Online for the information and allow the user to proceed .

This is my approach and have not started coding it yet .
I would like to know if  this is good enough an approach or are there are any other approaches that are better  and more feasible ?

Please  change the tags associated with the question if anyone feels they are not the right ones ..

thanks

**EDIT 1**.

I would add another level of username password to use that xml file online .. One that only the application would know

Comment: Have you considered storing the Usernames/Passwords in a password protected SQL database then connect to it from your app and authenticate with the information stored in the db? What do you mean 'not public to view' ? if i mirror your site with HTTrack i can download all the login information i could possibly want?

Comment: Hi Andris , thanks for replying I would add another level of username password to  use that webpage .. One that only the application would know .  I will add it as an edit . :) Again Im not sure about  the right approach

Answer (score 0):

You can create a WCF Service around your XML-File to authenticate the users. That way, you don't need to expose the file to the public.

Comment: Hi Sandro , thanks for your suggestion . I have not used WCF services before ,could you please suggest a website  that would help me kick start the research on that ..

Comment: Try http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article1386-basic-concepts-of-wcf-service-with-simple-example-.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It could be, depending on your exact scenario and requirements. A couple of things you may want to think about:

1. Consider storing hashes of the password in the database rather than the password itself. (And then send the hashed password over the wire rather than the password itself.) That way, if either your database or connection *are* ever compromised, you won't be exposing passwords.
2. Consider sending the authentication data over an SSL connection so it cannot be seen by eavesdroppers. (Especially if you choose to send raw passwords over the wire.)